# Prove the equivalence of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $A \subseteq$ B $\Leftrightarrow$ $A \cap B^c = \emptyset$

I tried Venn diagrams, but I didn't help

Comment: What is the product of sets? And $\overline B$? What about "Euler circles"? What does mean that $A \subseteq B$ *equals* something?

Comment: @azif00, I don't get your -1 at once: the product is multiplication of sets, it's negative of B set (obvious), equals means that it's the same as. And for circles I mix it up with diagrams

Comment: Oh, I didn't make the downvote. I just want a little of clarification.

Comment: The right words to use would be "intersection" and "complement".

Comment: I think that the appropriate interpretation is $A \cap B^c = \emptyset$. While "Euler circles" may be simply Venn diagrams.

Comment: If you have two statements, $P$ and $Q$, then the way to show $P \iff Q$ is to show [1] $P \implies Q~$ and [2] $Q \implies P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler to prove the contrapositive
$$A \nsubseteq B \Longleftrightarrow A \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$$
First suppose that $A \nsubseteq B$. This means that NOT all elements of $A$ belong to $B$.
This is equivalent to say that there is some element of $A$ not belonging to $B$.
But the set of elements of $A$ not belonging to $B$ is exactly $A \cap \overline{B}$.  Hence this is equivalent to say that $A \cap \overline{B}$ is not empty.